Stochastic differential equations with only time integrals
I want to reason about the stochastic differential equation
$$ dX_t = A_t X_t dt $$
Where $A_t$ is a matrix valued stochastic process, and hence $X_t$ is a vector valued stochastic process. Are there any good references for equations of this form?
In one variable, I know that if I write $A(t) = a(t) + \lambda \frac{dB_t}{dt} $ where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion, then the equation transforms to the standard Ito equation
$$ dX_t = a(t)X_t dt + \lambda X_t dB_t $$
and this generalises to several variables as well. Clearly this case is very well discussed in the literature everywhere.
However, it's also possible to transform the original equation into integral form
$$X_t = \int_0^s A_s X_s ds $$
where the integral is just an ordinary time integral of a stochastic process. Presumably, in order to do this, I need to place some integrability hypotheses on $A$. This suggests to me that the equation I'm considering makes sense. But inexplicably, I seem to find no treatment of SDEs of this form in the literature, and even time integrals of stochastic processes don't seem to get much of a look in in the literature.
For context, I'm interested in studying a stochastic form of the Schrödinger equation, where the Hamiltonian decomposes as $H(t) = H_0(t) + H_1(t)$, with $H_0$ the determistic control Hamiltonian, and $H_1(t)$ the (stochastic) noise Hamiltonian, which I assume to have mean 0.

Does $A_t$ depend on $X_t$ or does the randomness come from an external source? If not then I'm not sure why 'classical' ODE theory wouldn't apply where we just treat the coefficients as random (an ansatz that looks something like $X_t = \exp(\int_0^t A_s ds)X_0$ might work).

No the randomness is external: A_t is just a random linear map for all t. The Ansatz is almost right - you actually would need to correct the exponential for the non-commutativity via the Magnus expansion. This is essentially my idea. I'm just surprised that there isn't much explicit treatment of this in any of the literature I can find.

You may want to look at a text on Random Differential Equations. Xiaoying Han and Peter E. Kloeden have a good book on the subject that is available for free via the publisher. $dX_t  = A_tX_tdt$ as written appears to be an RDE not an SDE. The exampe of $A_t$ you give can make an SDE but for a different $A_t$ it is likely it'll be an RDE rather than an SDE.

OK - time for an update. Thanks to everyone who commented.
As pointed out by some commentators, these types of differential equations are called Random (Ordinary) Differential Equations. They have been studied for a long time, longer even that SDEs, which is perhaps unsurprising, since expressions like the one I wrote in my question are natural objects to write down. To quote Han and Kloeden's Random Ordinary Differential Equations and their Numerical Solution:
"RODEs seem to have had a shadow existence to SODEs, but have been around
for as long as if not longer than SODEs themselves and have many important applications, see e.g., Bunke [20], Neckel and Rupp [108], Sobczyk [123]. They also play a fundamental role in the theory of random dynamical systems, see Arnold [4]."
Perhaps this is unsurprising, since it turns out it's quite hard to say much about them. The article Random Ordinary Differential Equations (by J.L. Strand, available at https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82447522.pdf) proves a Picard-like theorem for equations of the form
$$\frac{dX}{dt} = f(X, t, \omega)$$
and discusses three different ways of interpreting what it means to be a solution: (almost surely) sample-pathwise, $L^p$ and $W^p$ (Sobolev). Perhaps surprisingly, even in the linear case (i.e. for the equation in my original question) it turns out that if we seek a path-wise solution with finite mean and variance (or equivalently, an $L^2$ solution), then we can only guarantee the existence of this solution if $A_t$ is essentially bounded.
Another (related) approach is the theory of rough differential equations, as summarised in Lyons' et. al.'s text Differential Equations
Driven by Rough Paths
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-71285-5
Finally, there is a stochastic analogue for the Magnus Expansion that includes the case in my question, and also allows for the addition of an Ito term. It's available here:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.01098
